# ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [1]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow

Here is my overall problem:
I am trying to build a tf.data.Dataset containing images. I am reading the imageIds (filenames) from a csv-file to be able to combine them with the corresponding label also found in the same csv-file.
[CSV-file Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3xRA.png)

```
df_imageIDs = pd.read_csv(file_labels,
                          usecols=["ImageId"])
df_imageIDs = df_imageIDs.apply(lambda ID: data_dir_train + ID, axis=1)
ds_filenames_images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_imageIDs.to_numpy())
```

After reading the Image IDs with pandas and adding the directory path, I map an image decoding function to my dataset using the method `tf.read_file`. This throws the error.

```
def decode_image(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=parameters["CHANNELS"])
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (parameters["IMAGE_HEIGHT"], parameters["IMAGE_WIDTH"]))
    return img

ds_images = ds_filenames_images.map(decode_image,
                                    num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Now, what I've tried before, is using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` which worked fine but the ImageIds were in the wrong order.

```
ds_filenames_imagesx = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_dir_train + "*.jpg",
                                                  shuffle=False)
```

The difference seems to be how pandas consumes the filenames although they have the same data type "string".
Printing out elements of the later method resulted in this:

```
tf.Tensor(/home/wid35008/airbus-ship-detection/train_v2/000155de5.jpg, shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Printing out the tensors of the method I want to use leads to that:

```
tf.Tensor(['/home/wid35008/airbus-ship-detection/train_v2/0002756f7.jpg'], shape=(1,), dtype=string)
```

Since I don't know how to interpret the differences nor knowing how to find a workaround. Does anybody have a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301642/shape-must-be-rank-0-but-is-rank-1-for-file-reader-op-readfile-with-input

Comment: I have .. that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to give a solution to myself and others who might stumble upon it.
I reshaped the dataset after creation so the Tensors inside would have the shape of a scalar again.

```
ds_filenames_images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_imageIDs.to_numpy())
ds_filenames_images = ds_filenames_images.map(lambda t: tf.reshape(t, []))
```

The docs give an more in-depth explanation for that. [Tensor Shapes](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#about_shapes)